# Wie können wir mehr erfahrenere Benutzer anlocken?

Tags: discussion, language

Wie Sie sicherlich schon bemerkt haben, bekommen Fragen, die auf Englisch verfasst sind, die meisten Views. Das lässt darauf schließen, dass der Großteil der Nutzer nicht genug Kenntnisse hat, um die Fragen zu verstehen, bzw. selbst Fragen auf Deutsch zu stellen. Darüber hinaus handelt es sich um sehr einfache Themem ([How to say "BTW" in German](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/38166/how-to-say-btw-in-german)).

*Und das ist auch gut so*.

Schön wäre es jedoch, wenn hier auch anspruchsvollere Fragen gestellt würden, damit auch die Beantworter der Fragen etwas nachdenken müssten, was wiederum auch ihnen Spaß machte.

**Was muss also getan werden, damit es bei German Language mehr Nutzer mit Niveau gibt?**

Comment: Beachte, dass erfahrene Lerner eher auf Deutsch fragen (nicht, dass das schlimm wäre).

Comment: Fragen auf Englisch landen oft bei den [HNQ](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot), deshalb die vielen Views. Ich denke das hat nichts mit den Sprachkenntnissen unserer User zu tun.

Comment: @Takkat Ich verstehe die Korrekturen beim Titel nicht. Ich meine, die Anzahl der erfahrenen Nutzer sollte steigen. Sagt man das etwa nicht so?

Comment: Der Komparativ Plural ist *erfahrenere* (= mehr erfahrene), mach einfach ein Rollback .

Comment: @ Es geht aber nicht um Komparativ sondern um Menge, ich möchte damit ausdrücken, dass die erfahrenen Nutzer wenig sind.

Comment: @Dreikäsehoch: so?

Comment: Ich denke, der Ursprungstitel war nicht nur grammatisch korrekt, sondern der richtige allgemein betrachtet. Es geht doch um erfahrene User an sich und nicht um jene, die besser sind als die, die schon da sind. Anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Ich schließe mich Takkats in einem Kommentar ausgeführter Meinung an: In der Regel kommen viele Views daher, dass eine Frage in der *Hot-Network-Questions*-Liste, auch bekannt als *HNQ* landet. Dadurch erscheint sie allen SE-Benutzern in der Seitenleiste und sehr viele klicken darauf, die sonst nie die Seite gesucht (oder gefunden) hätten.

Wir sollten unsere Fragen eher an dem Non-HNQ-Mittel bewerten, und ich denke, dass da die Fragen erfahrener Lerner nicht schlecht dastehen.